# How to exclude spec files from test runs in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to be able to exclude particular spec files from my test runs in cypress. I guess this will be some config entered into the `cypress.config.ts` file. All I have found is the `excludeSpecPattern` argument but this seems to be to exclude file patterns, not specific files/folders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **excludeSpecPattern** and define exact folders or files.

```
excludeSpecPattern: [
    '*/*/**/spec.cy.ts',
    '*/**/FolderToExclude'
],
```

If this doesn't work, then the defined path is wrong. Maybe this link will be helpful:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#excludeSpecPattern